# Load images from directory into picture box at certain intervals

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

Can anyone help me in loading images from directory into picture box at certain intervals.
For eg: i have some images in \Picture folder like 1.jpg,2.jpg..etc. 
So my requirement is to loop through Picture Directory and load 1.jpg into Picture box then wait for 5 sec, and then load 2.jpg into picture box.

Comment: Hi Cody I have written code like foreach(string fileName in Directory.GetFiles"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Image")) { pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(fileName); } But i got struck in loading other images at certain interval.

Comment: Did you try using a timer? You can set it to whatever interval you want. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is the name of the class you want, or you can drag one to your form from the toolbox.

Comment: Just goto google and type " slideshow c# winforms ". You will get umpteen results. Even you may get stack overflow results.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.Yes i have used timer eg:System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000); after this 5 sec how can i push second image from Images directory to picture box.

Comment: Whoops! Notice that I said to use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it, hope it will be helpful for others:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            moveTimer.Interval = 1000;
            moveTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(moveTimer_Tick);
            moveTimer.Start();
        }
    private void moveTimer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
               string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Dir", "*.jpg");  
               image = Image.FromFile(images[counter]);
               pictureBox.Width = image.Width;
               pictureBox.Height = image.Height;
               pictureBox.Image = image;


                // Move Image to new location
                pictureBox.Left = rand.Next(Math.Max(0, Bounds.Width - pictureBox.Width));
                pictureBox.Top = rand.Next(Math.Max(0, Bounds.Height - pictureBox.Height));

                if (counter < images.Count - 1)
                {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Dir", "*.jpg");
foreach (string image in images)
{
  pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(image);
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Just put this Code inside a `BackgroundWorker` at `doWork` Event.
If you want to keep slideshow Allays put it in a forever while loop

Comment: No this has given idea to loop through images but i handled code using Timer_Tick event as shown:pictureBox1.Left = rand.Next(Math.Max(1, Bounds.Width - pictureBox1.Width));
            pictureBox1.Top = rand.Next(Math.Max(1, Bounds.Height - pictureBox1.Height));

Comment: Image image = Image.FromFile(images[_counter]);
            pictureBox1.Width = image.Width;
            pictureBox1.Height = image.Height;

            pictureBox1.Image = image;

            if (_counter < images.Count -1)
            {
                _counter = _counter + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                _counter = 0;
            }

Answer (score 2):

Load it in picture box

```
var _with1 = openFileDialog1;

     _with1.Filter = ("Image Files |*.png; *.bmp; *.jpg;*.jpeg; *.gif;");
     _with1.FilterIndex = 4;
     //Reset the file name
     openFileDialog1.FileName = "";

     if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
       pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
     }
```

insert that path in db

```
try
     {
       con = new OleDbConnection(cs);
       con.Open();

       cmd = new OleDbCommand(cs);



       string cb = "insert into colorcodes(color,pic) VALUES ('" + colorcb.Text + "','" + openFileDialog1.FileName + "'  )";
       cmd = new OleDbCommand(cb);
       cmd.Connection = con;
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();
       MessageBox.Show("image Saved Successfully");
     }

     catch (Exception ex)
     {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

     }
```

use image.location to show in picture box again from db

```
 try
         {
           con = new OleDbConnection(cs);
           con.Open();
           cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT pic from  colorcodes where color= '" + colorcb.Text + "'  ", con);
           dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
           dr.Read();
           pictureBox2.ImageLocation = dr[0].ToString();
         }

         catch (Exception ex)
         {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Image[] imagecache;
    int cnt = 0;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // change dir with your image folder. or if you want to add formats you can add them with *.jpeg etc.
        string [] imageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\dir", "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        // cache files in folder
        imagecache = new Image[imageFiles.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < imageFiles.Length; i++)
        {

            imagecache[i] = Image.FromFile(imageFiles[i]);
        }


        timer1.Interval = 3000;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Start();
    }
    public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        picturebox.Image = null;
        picturebox.Image = imagecache[cnt];
        Application.DoEvents(); //to avoid memory leak in big files.

        cnt++;
        // if cnt exceeds files count, returns back to 0
        cnt = cnt % imagecache.Length;


    }
```

Comment: Please add some description too.

Comment: @OmSao added some comments as requested.

Comment: Application.DoEvents(); to avoid memory leak in big folders. not files :)